# How were the others able to handle the power of the stone?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy

I understand that Peter Quill was able to handle infinity stone without destroying himself possibly because his father is a (powerful?) alien of an unknown species. But how were the other [*Guardians of the Galaxy*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2015381/) able to handle the power of the stone?

Comment: Probably due to the "power of fellowship/community/friendship" or something as fuzzy. ;-)

Comment: I suspect the same :)

Comment: Though, one could also ask how *Ronan* could control it as well, but I guess he's quite powerful, too.

Comment: Because all are non-human ;)

Comment: Remember, during the Collector's explanation of what the Infinity Stones are he mentions "a group was able to share the energy" (although they were eventually destroyed).

Comment: Peter's dad was an "angel" according to his mom. Also the others do not touch the stone directly.
@Oliver_C the other group tried to share the energy of all stones if I remember correctly...

Comment: They shared the power of the stone as a group ... no individual person of the *Guardians* could do it by themselves.

Answer (score 4):

Over the course of the movie, we see three different "entities" try to use the power of the stone:

- The Collector's assistant (daughter, I think?) tries and quite spectacularly fails, because she's just a mortal and can't handle it.
- Ronan tries, and briefly succeeds, before welding it onto his war hammer. Note that, in the "flashback" scenes during The Collector's exposition, we also see the stone being wielded *through* another object, which appears to make the stone much more manageable. We know that Ronan is not a 'normal' mortal, so he was able to survive the stone for the short time it took to attach it to his weapon. However, it was clearly trying to destroy him even during that time.
- The entire Guardians team, who were the only ones that seemed able to *control* the stone. But note that Peter's ability to hold the stone was hinted at in the final scene as possibly being due to his non-human father. The rest of the Guardians were only in contact with the stone *through Peter*.

Basically, the way I interpreted the scene is:

Quill was acting as a buffer, taking the brunt of the force of the stone for himself, but able to handle it because of his nature. The rest of the Guardians were acting as a kind of "focus": by supporting him as a team, it allowed Peter to channel the energy of the stone directly without overwhelming him.

(On a side note: this is also the reason why the Infinity Gauntlet exists in the first place: apparently, even an immortal being like Thanos would be unable to control the stones directly; he needs to embed them into an *object* that he can use to control and channel their power in order to use them.)

Comment: `...able to handle it because of his nature` - I'm not sure Peter actually could. His face did start to disintegrate until the others joined in.

Comment: @Oliver_C my suspicion is that *anyone* would have problems controlling a stone directly for very long (even, possibly, a titan like Thanos); Quill was just "better" able to handle it than most people.

Answer (score 0):

Quill was able to handle the power because he is only half human. The other half is Spartoi, a humanoid species with much longer life spans than humans, (upwards of 200years). Between this and the fact that he was sharing the power of the stone with the other 3 all of whom are non-human allowed the power to be controllable for a short time.

Comment: Spartoi? When is it established?

Comment: In the comics his father is Spartoi, but there's evidence that the creators of this version of Quill aren't going with that route. See: [Who is Peter Quill/Star-Lord's father?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/64654/21267)